# Locating and printing text from image

Tags: python, string, image, text, python-tesseract

Is there a way to use Python to locate and print the text from images such as these?

I've tried **pytesseract**, but it doesn't seem to do the job. Apparently it's only fit for images containing nothing but text.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend the Google Cloud Vision API

You can try it out [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop)

Results:

[image]